# Is Xcode 8 developer signing broken today (1/28/2017 12:40 PM US EST)?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am getting errors in Xcode 8 in my app that have to do with my 'Signing' configuration:

An unexpected failure occurred while logging in (Underlying error code 1100).

I renewed my developer license back in December 2016 and things have been fine until today. I have no evidence to believe that anything has changed with my account.

When I go to developer.apple.com and choose 'Account' to attempt to manage my developer cert, I get a generic page saying "We'll be back soon". I believe the two things are connected.

I know this is not the best place to ask, but I'm seeing nothing when searching Google to indicate the site is down today (1/28/2017 12:40 PM EST). Also when I check the Apple server status page, it reports all servers up.

Is anyone else experiencing this? Where does one report such things?

UPDATE: I cannot contact developer support because that requires a login which fails. Note that my apple id login works elsewhere.

Thanks,
Peter...

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? - Sorry that's some potentially esoteric humor. Let me go try logging into my account and see if it works for me.

Comment: Yeah I can't login either

Comment: Yes It's down since last few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to scheduled maintenance, some services are unavailable.

https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

Comment: Services back online.